# C Memory Management -> Queue

Tags: c, algorithm, memory, segmentation-fault

Okay so i have this Queue implementation that works, but i'm having some memory leak that doesn't let a if else operations runs after that.

File queue_arr.h

```
#define MaxQ 100

typedef struct {
    int array[MaxQ];
    int front;
    int back;
    int size;
}*Queue;


Queue init();
int enqueue(Queue q, int v);
int dequeue(Queue q, int *v);
int front(Queue q, int *v);
int isEmpty(Queue q);
```

File queue_arr.c

```
#include "queue_arr.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


Queue init() {
    Queue q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    q->front = 0;
    q->back = 0;
    q->size = 0;
    return q;
}

int enqueue(Queue q, int v) {
    if(q->size==MaxQ)
        return 0;
    q->array[q->back] = v;
    q->back++;
    if(q->back == MaxQ)
        q->back = 0;
    q->size++;
    return 1;

}

int dequeue(Queue q, int *v) {
    if(q->size == 0)
        return 0;
    *v = q->array[q->front];
    q->front++;
    if(q->front == MaxQ)
        q->front =0;
    q->size--;
    return 1;   
}

int front(Queue q, int *v) {
    if(q->size==0)
        return 0;
    *v = q->array[q->front];
    return 1;   
}

int isEmpty(Queue q) {
    if(q->size == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    Queue teste = init();
    int *aux;
    *aux = -1;
    printf("Value : %d\n",*aux );

    enqueue(teste,5);
    enqueue(teste,10);
    enqueue(teste,15);
    front(teste,aux);

    printf("Next costumer: %d\n",*aux );

    dequeue(teste,aux);

    printf("Costumer %d left queue\n",*aux );

    dequeue(teste,aux);

    printf("Costumer %d left queue\n",*aux );

    dequeue(teste,aux);

    printf("Costume %d left queue\n",*aux );

    int random = 10;
    if(random == 10)
        printf("asdasdasd\n");


}
```

The last if and else statement doest not work, i noticed cause i was trying to do a isEmpty if clause, and keep leading me to segmentation fault.

Without the last three lines, the code compiles and runs, with no errors. But with that i just keep getting a segmentation fault.

Does anybody knows the problem ?

Comment: Since this is valid c++ I cannot arbitrarily remove the c++ tag, please pick one either c or c++

Comment: Thank you, even you didn't helped at all.

Comment: `Queue q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(Queue));` --> `Queue q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(*q));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your segmentaion fault because of this

```
int *aux;

*aux = -1;
```

you should

```
aux = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

before

```
*aux = -1;
```

but I don't think that is what you want, instead you should just do it

```
int aux = -1;
```

and when calling `dequeue`

```
dequeue(teste, &aux);
```

Also I would recomend you fix these other issues

1. You don't need to cast `malloc`
2. You should check that `malloc` didn't return `NULL` otherwise you will dereference a 
   `NULL` pointer which is undefined behavior.
3. Also, your `malloc` call is passing the wrong size. A possible fix is to use

   ```
   Queue q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
   ```

   But I would actually recommend to avoid hiding the fact that variables are pointers completely.
4. You do have a memory leak but that is not a cause for a segmentaion fault, you should just call `free(teste)` at the end of `main()`.
5. Your `main()` doesn't return you should, also add `return 0;` at the end of `main()` after `free()`

I fixed your code, hope this helps

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MaxQ 100

typedef {
    int array[MaxQ];
    int front;
    int back;
    int size;
} *Queue;


Queue init() {
    Queue q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
    if (q == NULL)
        return NULL;
    q->front = 0;
    q->back = 0;
    q->size = 0;
    return q;
}

int enqueue(Queue q, int v) { 
    if (q == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(q->size==MaxQ)
        return 0;
    q->array[q->back] = v;
    q->back++;
    if(q->back == MaxQ)
        q->back = 0;
    q->size++;
    return 1;

}

int dequeue(Queue q, int *v) {
    if (q == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(q->size == 0)
        return 0;
    *v = q->array[q->front];
    q->front++;
    if(q->front == MaxQ)
        q->front =0;
    q->size--;
    return 1;
}

int front(Queue q, int *v) {
    if (q == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(q->size==0)
        return 0;
    *v = q->array[q->front];
    return 1;
}

int isEmpty(Queue q) {
    if (q == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(q->size == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    Queue teste = init();
    if (teste == NULL)
        return -1;
    int aux;

    aux = -1;
    printf("Value : %d\n", aux);

    enqueue(teste,5);
    enqueue(teste,10);
    enqueue(teste,15);
    front(teste, &aux);

    printf("Next costumer: %d\n", aux );

    dequeue(teste, &aux);

    printf("Costumer %d left queue\n", aux );

    dequeue(teste, &aux);

    printf("Costumer %d left queue\n", aux );

    dequeue(teste, &aux);

    printf("Costume %d left queue\n", aux );

    int random = 10;
    if(random == 10)
        printf("asdasdasd\n");
    free(teste);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you again, you totally nailed it. Sorry i can't upvote, but your answer is by far the best. Only you could answer to the real problem, and explain the rest was also a good help.

Comment: I know you can't upvote, but you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can't decide whether a `Queue` is a pointer to something or the something.

```
typedef struct {
    int array[MaxQ];
    int front;
    int back;
    int size;
}*Queue;
```

This says a `Queue` is a pointer to a bunch of things.

```
Queue q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
q->front = 0;
```

This allocates enough bytes to hold a `Queue`, which is just a pointer, and then attempts to use the thing it points to. But you never allocated space for anything but a pointer.

Comment: You might be right, not contesting. But i don't have memory problems on the Queue functions. And i've also tried another implementation, with a struct for a queue and the typedef for the *Queue (with the pointer), so i could allocate space the right way, even so iharob answer was the one i needed.

Comment: @Duozhasht Think about it. Where you do allocate space for `q->front`? You allocate space for `Queue` itself, but that's a pointer.

Comment: So how it would be the right way to allocate that ? Change the structure itself or the way I alloc the space ?

Comment: @Duozhasht `Queue q = malloc (sizeof (*Queue));` Allocate enough space for the thing a `Queue` points to.

Answer (score 1):

```
Queue q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
```

Congratulations, `sizeof(Queue)` is 4 (or 8) bytes since it's a pointer.